# Cron job every day at 2am EST

Tags: javascript, firebase, cron

How would I go about scheduling a cron tab every night at 2AM EST time?

It's my impression that the cron schedule below will run at 2AM UTC not EST. Is that correct?

[image]

**Going further:** to add to this, how could I have the cron schedule run at 2AM on each of the six US timezones?

Comment: I suggest you make an attempt at solving the problem, then edit the question explain what you did and how it doesn't work the way you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's my impression that the cron schedule below will run at 2AM UTC
> not EST. Is that correct?

Yes, cron job will run on UTC time.

So to register cron on 2 AM EST you have to convert that time into UTC,
and the time is in 24-hours clock

**EST:**

New York, NY, USA ( EST UTC-5)
**2 AM**

Diff from UTC is **-5**

**UTC**

In UTC time will be ( 7 - 5 = 2 EST ) **7AM**

CRON at 0 7 * * *

and for multiple 2AM US timezone first watch for diff and register cron on that UTC.

also, watch for  **daylight savings**